# Passar vários parâmetros para uma consulta SQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Vamos supor que tenho os seguintes `CPF's:`

```
65568752877
86924355382
55317961378
82331493146
```

Gostaria de passa-los como parâmetro em uma consulta `SQL`, estou tentando da seguinte forma:

Trecho SQL

```
... " AND Beneficiario.Codigo IN ('"+codigo+"') ");
```

E depois

```
List<Cliente> lista = buscar(c, " 65568752877, 86924355382, 55317961378, 82331493146 ");
```

Porém da esse erro:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data
>   type varchar to bigint.

Quando passo apenas um CPF funciona, o problema está quando tento passar mais de um.

Quando rodo a com os valores dessa forma funciona:

```
AND Beneficiario.Codigo IN
(65568752877, 86924355382, 55317961378, 82331493146)
```

OBS: Os códigos (CPF) não são fixos, eles podem mudar e a quantidade de códigos passados por parâmetros também pode mudar.

Comment: Poste blocos do código ao invés de trechos, fica mais fácil de tentar te ajudar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso está ocorrendo, pois o seu campo codigo é BIGINT e você está tentando passar para ele esse valor:

```
"65568752877, 86924355382, 55317961378, 82331493146"
```

Esse valor não pode ser convertido em BIGINT, já que se trata de uma String. O correto é fazer exatamente da maneira que funciona, ou seja:

```
(65568752877, 86924355382, 55317961378, 82331493146)
```

A clausula acima especfica que você quer registros onde o código seja 65568752877 **ou** 86924355382 **ou** 55317961378 **ou** 55317961378

A sua função **buscar**, portanto, deve receber a string "65568752877,86924355382, 55317961378,82331493146" e, internamente, tratá-la, para passar para o SQL corretamente.

**Atualização - Código para transformar uma String em uma cláusula IN:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(montaClausulaInSQL("12222,2233,2232",true));
}

public static String montaClausulaInSQL(String valor, Boolean valorNumerico) {
    String[] vetor = valor.split(",");

    String clausulaIn = "(";

    for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
        clausulaIn = clausulaIn + (!valorNumerico?"'":"") + vetor[i] + (!valorNumerico?"'":"") + ",";
    }

    clausulaIn = clausulaIn.substring(0,clausulaIn.length()-1);
    clausulaIn = clausulaIn + ")";

    return clausulaIn;
}
```

A função *montaClausulaInSQL* recebe uma String separada por "," e retorna uma cláusula IN para ser utilizada no SQL. Caso o valor do campo a ser feita a Query seja númerico, deve-se passar true no 2o parametro. Nesse caso, não será colocado o apóstrofe em cada elemento do IN.

Comment: Entendi, mas como posso passar todos esses códigos? Esses códigos não são fixos, eles podem ser diferentes.

Comment: Vou pegar um exemplo aqui de como você pode tratar uma String para coloca-la na clausula IN. Daqui a pouco edito a minha pergunta.

Comment: @Techies, favor verificar o codigo.

Comment: opa, muito obrigado, consegui resolver o problema.